# Chapter numbering in XSL-FO

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have xml of the form:
    
    
     Chapter 1
      
        Chapter 1.1
        
           Chapter 1.1.1
         
       
     
     Chapter 1.2

```
<CHAPTER>
 <LONG-NAME>Chapter 2</LONG-NAME>
  <CHAPTER>
 <LONG-NAME>Chapter 2.1</LONG-NAME>
 </CHAPTER>
 <CHAPTER>
 <LONG-NAME>Chapter 2.2</LONG-NAME>
 </CHAPTER>
</CHAPTER>
</REPORT-BODY>
```

there can be any number of chapters inside one chapter.
how to write xsl-fo to get the out pdf as below:

```
1. Chapter 1
1.1 chapter 1.1
1.1.1 Chapter 1.1.1
1.2 Chapter 1.2

2.Chapter 2
2.1 Chapter 2.1
2.2 Chapter 2.2
```

i tried using:

```
 <xsl:template
    match="CHAPTER/LONG-NAME">
   <fo:block
        color="#374B80"
        font-size="12px"
        font-family="Helvetica"
        font-weight="bold"
        padding-top="3px"
        padding-bottom="3px">
<xsl:if test="ancestor::REPORT-BODY">
    <xsl:variable name="chapNum">
    <xsl:number from="CHAPTER" count="LONG-NAME" format="1 " level="any"/>
    </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:value-of select="$chapNum"/>    
   </xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="ancestor::CHAPTER">
<xsl:variable name="chapNumber">
<xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
  <xsl:number from="CHAPTER/CHAPTER" count="LONG-NAME" format="1. " level="any"/>
  </xsl:variable>   
  <xsl:value-of select="$chapNumber"/>  
   </xsl:if>      
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </fo:block>
   </xsl:template>
```

but i am not able to achieve the required numbering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `xsl:number` like this:

```
<xsl:number format="1. " count="CHAPTER" level="multiple"/>
```

You should be able to replace your template with this one:

```
<xsl:template match="CHAPTER/LONG-NAME">
    <fo:block
        color="#374B80"
        font-size="12px"
        font-family="Helvetica"
        font-weight="bold"
        padding-top="3px"
        padding-bottom="3px">
        <xsl:number format="1. " count="CHAPTER" level="multiple"/>     
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```