# XSL: Multi level numbering

Tags: xslt

I am new to xsl.

This is style sheet template.

```
<xsl:template match="LI|li">
    <fo:list-item>
        <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="name(..)!='OL'">
                      <xsl:number format="1."/>
                    </xsl:when>

                    <xsl:when test="name(../..)!='OL'">
                        <xsl:number format="(a)"/>
                    </xsl:when>

                    <xsl:when test="name(../../..)!='OL'">
                        <xsl:number format="(1)"/>
                    </xsl:when>

                    <xsl:when test="name(../../../..)!='OL'">
                        <xsl:number format="(i)"/>
                    </xsl:when>

                    <xsl:when test="name(../../../../..)!='OL'">
                        <xsl:number format="(A)"/>
                    </xsl:when>

                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:text>&#xB7;</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-label>

        <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-body>
    </fo:list-item>
</xsl:template>
```

this style sheet converts `<li>` (dot) into numbers by the above template.

```
<xsl:template match="SectionsArticlesToPrintVOExRow" mode="terms">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="AmendOperationCode='DELETED'">
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
            <fo:block padding-top="12pt"  font-size="{$HeaderFontSize}" font-family="Times" id="S{UniqueId}" font-weight="bold">
                <xsl:if test="Label and (Label!='')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Label"/>
                    <xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block/>

            <xsl:if test="ObjectType='ARTICLE'">
                <fo:block font-size="9pt" padding-top="5pt" padding-bottom="5pt" font-family="Times" white-space-collapse="false" linefeed-treatment="preserve" text-align="justify">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="InsertByReference='Y'">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="ReferenceText"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="ArticleText"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </fo:block>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

- Label: will have the sequence number.
- ArticleText : will have the terms clause.

  Input:

  `<SectionsArticlesToPrintVORow>`

  `<UniqueId>ARTICLE33112</UniqueId>`

  `<StructureLevel>2</StructureLevel>`

  `<ObjectType>ARTICLE</ObjectType>`

  `<ParentId>12324</ParentId>`

  `<DocumentId>112943</DocumentId>`

  `<DocumentType>B</DocumentType>`

  `<DisplaySequence>20</DisplaySequence>`

  `<Label> 1.1 </Label>`

  `<Title>Price Increases</Title>`

  `<ArticleNumber>JF0111</ArticleNumber>`

  `<ArticleText>

  Only supplies will be used with the Product.&nbsp; All consumable 
  supplies included in the Master FSM will be provided by Servicing 
  Providers without additional freight charges to the Customer.&nbsp;
  Consumable supplies not covered under this Master FSM are:
  <li>  <li><u>MFDs</u> - paper and staples, unless otherwise indicated herein. </li>  </ul>  <li>  <li><u>Stand-Alone Facsimiles</u>&nbsp; Process kit, toner, drum, ink film  and developer kit are excluded.&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </li></ul>  <blockquote>  Excluded supplies may be purchased from other vendors or Servicing   Providers.&nbsp; If another vendor's brand supplies are used, with the exception   of paper, maintenance will be voided and customer will waive certain rights under   manufacturer's warranty.&nbsp; Servicing Providers will bill separately for   excluded supplies not covered.&nbsp; Staples and facsimile supplies may be   purchased separately from  issuance of a PO. </blockquote>  2.4.<li>  <li>  <u>Expedited Delivery</u>. Customer may request expedited delivery for consumables.   Toshiba will make its best effort to provide consumable rushorders within twenty-four  (24) hours.&nbsp;Expedited delivery charges shall apply and rates depend on the method  ofdelivery and will be quoted at the time of request. Expedited delivery charges shall  be billed separately and directly by the Dealer.  </li>  </ul>  </ArticleText>`

  `<ArticleVersionId>3801</ArticleVersionId>`

  `<ArticleId>3557</ArticleId>`

  `<CatId>33112</CatId>`

  `<InsertByReference>N</InsertByReference>`

  `</SectionsArticlesToPrintVORow>`

Output is:

```
 2.4. Consumables
```

Only Toshiba-brand supplies will be used with the Product. All consumable supplies included in the Master FSM will
be provided by Toshiba Servicing Providers without additional freight charges to the Customer. Consumable supplies
not covered under this Master FSM are:

```
 1. MFDs - paper and staples, unless otherwise indicated herein.  

 2. Stand-Alone Facsimiles Process kit, toner, drum, ink film and developer kit are excluded.
```

Excluded supplies may be purchased from other vendors or Servicing Providers. If another vendor's non-Toshiba
brand supplies are used, with the exception of paper, Toshiba's maintenance will be voided and customer will waive
certain rights under Toshiba's manufacturer's warranty. Servicing Providers will bill separately for excluded supplies
not covered. Staples and facsimile supplies may be purchased separately from Toshiba by issuance of a PO.

But the desired output:

```
2.4. Consumables
```

Only Toshiba-brand supplies will be used with the Product. All consumable supplies included in the Master FSM will
be provided by Toshiba Servicing Providers without additional freight charges to the Customer. Consumable supplies
not covered under this Master FSM are:

```
2.4.1. MFDs - paper and staples, unless otherwise indicated herein.  

2.4.2. Stand-Alone Facsimiles Process kit, toner, drum, ink film and developer kit are excluded.
```

Excluded supplies may be purchased from other vendors or Servicing Providers. If another vendor's non-Toshiba
brand supplies are used, with the exception of paper, Toshiba's maintenance will be voided and customer will waive
certain rights under Toshiba's manufacturer's warranty. Servicing Providers will bill separately for excluded supplies
not covered. Staples and facsimile supplies may be purchased separately from Toshiba by issuance of a PO.

how can I achieve desired output.

Updated.

Comment: It will be easier to understand what you need if you post some example input.

Comment: I updated with some more info. kindly let me know you need more info to understand.

Comment: @KRaju  Please post enough code to reproduce the problem - including an example of the XML input you are working with. See: [mcve]

Comment: Updated with sample xml. Thank you.

Comment: I have tidied up your code to make it more readable. It seems your sample input isn't valid XML (the `<li>` and the `<ul>` tags don't match). You have to fix your input before hoping to get sensible output.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034774/chapter-numbering-in-xsl-fo

Comment: Apologies , I gave wrong information. I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the level="multiple" option on xsl:number, e.g.

```
<xsl:number level="multiple" format="1.1.1"/>
```